# Skip authentication on a razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor pages application which uses ADFS for authentication. I do not want a particular razor page to be authenticated. How do I achieve this? I know we can skip authorization on a folder/page using `.AddRazorPagesOptions` but how do I skip authentication? Please see the code I have below:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSession();

            app.Use(
                (next) =>
                    {
                        return async context =>
                            {
                                var user = context.User;
                                if (user == null || !user.Identities.Any(identity => identity.IsAuthenticated))
                                {
                                    await context.ChallengeAsync();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //await app.SetAuthData(accessor);
                                    await app.ConfigureEntitySession(accessor, env);
                                    await next.Invoke(context);
                                }

                            };
                    });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try

```
services.AddRazorPages()
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{        
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/YourPage/...");
});
```

Comment: yes i did try that, but from what i understand AllowAnonymousToPage is an Authorization filter but not authentication filter. It asks me for credentials to logineven though i included it in the AddRazorPagesOptions -> AllowAnonymousToPage. I need to skip authentication on that one page.